# Registering new user in firebase via Android application is succeed but in console it shows no user data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am developing an simple app to get votings from users.

i am using **FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()** method for signing up the new user using email and password. as the app runs it shows no errors and the registration process, verification process and login process also succeed and the other activities of the app is working fine.

when i check the firebase auth console for registered users it shows empty.(i am confused here, the registeration is succesfull so it should have added the user in the auth console right?)

here is my register.java code...

```
  mRegButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
           String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
           String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
           String fullname = mFullname.getText().toString();

           if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
               mEmail.setError("Email is required.");
               return;
           }

           if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
               mPassword.setError("Password is required.");
               return;
           }

           if (password.length() < 6){
               mPassword.setError("Password should be >= 6 characters");
               return;
           }

           fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                   if (task.isSuccessful()){

                       FirebaseUser fuser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                       fuser.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                   Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Registered Succesfully. Please verify your email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               }else{
                                   Toast.makeText(Registration.this, task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               }

                           }
                       });

                       Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "User created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                       DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID);
                       Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                       user.put("fName",fullname);
                       user.put("email",email);
                       documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                               Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: User profile is created for "+userID);

                           }
                       });
                       startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));

                   }else {
                       Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Error !" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

               }
           });
       }
```

let me know if anything wrong in my code..

Firebase console for authentication
[image: firebase console for authentication]

Firebase authentication sign in method..
[image]

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Comment: Besides that, have you tried to attach a failure listener to see if something goes wrong?